# jquery object has no method live

Tags: javascript, jquery, live

hello i have an overlay in jquery, and i's work only with the version 1.6 but i want to add the latest library 1.9.1 and i have this error, Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live' at line 20 on my code, my code is this.

```
(function($) {

    $('a[data-reveal-id]').live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');
        $('#'+modalLocation).reveal($(this).data());
    });


    $.fn.reveal = function(options) {


        var defaults = {  
            animation: 'fadeAndPop', //fade, fadeAndPop, none
            animationspeed: 300, //how fast animtions are
            closeonbackgroundclick: true, //if you click background will modal close?
            dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal' //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
        }; 

        var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options); 

        return this.each(function() {

            var modal = $(this),
                topMeasure  = parseInt(modal.css('top')),
                topOffset = modal.height() + topMeasure,
                locked = false,
                modalBG = $('.reveal-modal-bg');


            if(modalBG.length == 0) {
                modalBG = $('<div class="reveal-modal-bg" />').insertAfter(modal);
            }           


            modal.bind('reveal:open', function () {
              modalBG.unbind('click.modalEvent');
                $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).unbind('click.modalEvent');
                if(!locked) {
                    lockModal();
                    if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
                        modal.css({'top': $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset, 'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible'});
                        modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
                        modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
                            "top": $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure + 'px',
                            "opacity" : 1
                        }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());                   
                    }
                    if(options.animation == "fade") {
                        modal.css({'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible', 'top': $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
                        modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
                        modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
                            "opacity" : 1
                        }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());                   
                    } 
                    if(options.animation == "none") {
                        modal.css({'visibility' : 'visible', 'top':$(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
                        modalBG.css({"display":"block"});   
                        unlockModal()               
                    }
                }
                modal.unbind('reveal:open');
            });     


            modal.bind('reveal:close', function () {
              if(!locked) {
                    lockModal();
                    if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
                        modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                        modal.animate({
                            "top":  $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset + 'px',
                            "opacity" : 0
                        }, options.animationspeed/2, function() {
                            modal.css({'top':topMeasure, 'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden'});
                            unlockModal();
                        });                 
                    }   
                    if(options.animation == "fade") {
                        modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                        modal.animate({
                            "opacity" : 0
                        }, options.animationspeed, function() {
                            modal.css({'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
                            unlockModal();
                        });                 
                    }   
                    if(options.animation == "none") {
                        modal.css({'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
                        modalBG.css({'display' : 'none'});  
                    }       
                }
                modal.unbind('reveal:close');
            });     


        modal.trigger('reveal:open')

            //Close Modal Listeners
            var closeButton = $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
              modal.trigger('reveal:close')
            });

            if(options.closeonbackgroundclick) {
                modalBG.css({"cursor":"pointer"})
                modalBG.bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
                  modal.trigger('reveal:close')
                });
            }
            $('body').keyup(function(e) {
                if(e.which===27){ modal.trigger('reveal:close'); } // 27 is the keycode for the Escape key
            });



            function unlockModal() { 
                locked = false;
            }
            function lockModal() {
                locked = true;
            }   

        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: [version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Answer (score 17):

[`live` was removed from jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/live/) as of v1.9. It's been deprecated for several versions (since v1.7).

Here's what the docs say about rewriting it to use `delegate` or `on` (I added the comments above each call):

> Rewriting the `.live()` method in terms of its successors is straightforward; these are templates for equivalent calls for all three event attachment methods:

```
// `live`, now removed
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+

// `delegate`, superceded but not deprecated
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+

// `on`, the latest 
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

So in your case, instead of:

```
$('a[data-reveal-id]').live('click', function(e) { // ...
```

you'd want

```
$(document).delegate('a[data-reveal-id]', 'click', function(e) { // ...
// Or
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-reveal-id]', function(e) { // ...
```

However, you can usually find a container element closer to the elements you want to hook, and if so, you want to use that rather than `document`. For instance, suppose all of your `data-reveal-id` anchors are in a `div` with the `id` `"stuff"`. Rather than

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-reveal-id]', function(e) { // ...
```

you'd be better off hooking the click a bit closer to the anchors:

```
$('#stuff').on('click', 'a[data-reveal-id]', function(e) { // ...
```

But if there's no suitable common ancestor element other than `document`, you can use `document`.

Comment: This has got to be one of the most common statements revolving jQuery lately. :D

Comment: and haw i can change the live to something else? maybe you know some other function for that?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, it's been removed as of v1.9: http://api.jquery.com/live/

You can refactor your code, however, to something like:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', 'a[data-reveal-id]', function(e) { ... });
```

Comment: TJ Fogarty thank you very very much, have a nice day Ivan Ivković thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

And there is also the [migrate](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/31/jquery-migrate-1-1-0-released/) plugin. You can use it to detect deprecated and removed features.